# What does plugin migration mean in Redmine?

Tags: plugins, migration, redmine

I am trying to add a plugin named [Redmine Scrumbler](https://github.com/256MbTeam/Redmine-Scrumbler) to Redmine. So far I have created a folder named "plugins" in the root folder where Redmine is installed and I've cloned the plugin from this repository [Redmine Scrumbler](https://github.com/256MbTeam/Redmine-Scrumbler) to that folder.

Now [this](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugins) says that if the plugin requires migration I have to migrate it. Now how do I know if the plugin requires migration or not? Also what exactly does plugin migration mean in Redmine?

Also I didn't see "plugins" folder in the root folder where Redmine is installed. Does that folder need to be created or not? (The version of Redmine is 2.4.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now how do I know if the plugin requires migration or not?

Check plugin folder `plugin_root/db/migrate`. If the folder exists and have some migrations (files) then plugin requires to run migration. Mentioned plugin requires migration (https://github.com/256MbTeam/Redmine-Scrumbler/tree/master/db/migrate)

> Also what exactly does plugin migration mean in redmine?

The plugin will update the DB structure. Plugins usually create some additional tables/columns.

> Also I didn't see "plugins" folder in the root folder where Redmine is installed. Does that folder need to be created or not? (The version of Redmine is 2.4.1)

Yes. The folder should be created.

PS mentioned plugin's last update time was two years ago. It looks like the plugin is not supported any more.

Answer (score 0):

Redmine Scrumbler isn't officially supported on versions >2.x. You shouldn't trust it.